# Python def in if True don't return

Tags: python, depth-first-search

This code,, `if count >= 3 : print("test")` success but `return True` not working.. why..?!?

```
def dfs(a, b, i, count):
    
    if a<=-1 or a>=7 or b<=-1 or b>=7:
        return False
    
    if lists[a][b] == i and lists[a][b] > 0:
        
        lists[a][b] = -1 #확인 했음을 표시
        count += 1;
        
        dfs(a+1, b, i, count)
        dfs(a-1, b, i, count)
        dfs(a, b+1, i, count)
        dfs(a, b-1, i, count)
        
        if count >= 3 :
            print("test") #THIS PRINT SUCCESS!!
            return True   #BUT DON'T return True!!
        else:
            return False
            
    return False
        

lists = []
for i in range(7):
    lists.append(list(map(int, input().split(" "))))

result = 0

for a in range(0, 7):
    for b in range(0, 7):
        if dfs(a, b, lists[a][b], 0) == True:
            
            #Never run.. this codes..
            print("result up?") 
            result += 1

print( result )
```

input data is

```
2 1 5 1 1 3 4
2 1 5 1 3 5 3
2 3 4 5 2 2 4
4 4 3 2 3 1 3
4 3 5 3 1 4 3
5 4 4 3 3 5 5
2 1 3 5 1 1 2
```

please help me ㅠㅠ..

Comment: The only situation in which that would print but not return true would be when there's a bug in CPython. Do you perhaps have a reason as to why you have made this conclusion?

Comment: Also, I ran your code and it does not print anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in

```py
        dfs(a+1, b, i, count)
        dfs(a-1, b, i, count)
        dfs(a, b+1, i, count)
        dfs(a, b-1, i, count)
```

If you change it to

```py
        print(dfs(a+1, b, i, count))
        print(dfs(a-1, b, i, count))
        print(dfs(a, b+1, i, count))
        print(dfs(a, b-1, i, count))
```

Suddenly the "missing" return true appears. The problem here is that you don't do anything with the actually returned "True". So you need to do something with this returned value, I'm not certain what you're attempting, but I hope it answers the question as to what happened

Part of the output

```
False
False
False
False
test
True
False
False
```